# List Query - How to get attachments link

Tags: jquery, query, attachments

I have a query:

```
function consultaPropostas() {

    var customlist ;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle( 'WO_Vendor_Proposal' );    
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml( '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
       '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>' );

    this.customlist = oList.getItems( camlQuery );
    clientContext.load( this.customlist );
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(            
        Function.createDelegate( this, onQuerySucceededConsultaPropostas ),
        Function.createDelegate( this, onQueryFailedConsultaPropostas ));

}
function onQuerySucceededConsultaPropostas() 
{
    try{
        var listPropostas = [];
        var getCampo3 = 'WO_x0020_ID';
        var listItemEnumerator = this.customlist.getEnumerator();

        while ( listItemEnumerator.moveNext() ) 
        {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            if( oListItem.get_item( getCampo3 ) != null )
                if( oListItem.get_item( getCampo3 ).$M_1.toString().localeCompare( urlParams['ID'] ) === 0 )
                    listPropostas.push( {   ID: oListItem.get_item( "ID" ), 
                                            Vendor: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "Vendor" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "Vendor" ) ),
                                            CostEffort: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "Cost_x0020_Effort_x0020__x0028_V" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "Cost_x0020_Effort_x0020__x0028_V" ) ),
                                            ManpowerEffort: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "Manpower_x0020_Effort_x0020__x00" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "Manpower_x0020_Effort_x0020__x00" ) ),
                                            StartDate: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "Start_x0020_Date_x0020__x0028_Ve" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "Start_x0020_Date_x0020__x0028_Ve" ) ),
                                            EndDate: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "End_x0020_Date" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "End_x0020_Date" ) ),
                                            Declined: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "Declined" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "Declined" ) ),
                                            NrVersion: ( ( isNull( oListItem.get_item( "NrVersion" ) ) ) ? "" : oListItem.get_item( "NrVersion" ) ) } );
        }


   }catch(err){
        alert( err );
    }
 }

function onQueryFailedConsultaPropostas( sender, args ) { alert( "Failed" ); }
```

And now I want to get the links of attachments..
I tryed `oListItem.get_item( "Attachments" )` but it only returns `true`.
Is it possible to get link of Attachments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SP.ListItem.attachmentFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246450(v=office.15).aspx) to retrieve the collection of attachments that are associated with the list item.

### How to retrieve list items with attachments using JSOM

```
function getListItems(listTitle,success,error)
{ 
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list =  web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   ctx.load(items,'Include(AttachmentFiles)'); //Note: AttachmentFiles is requested explicitly
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
       success(items);  
     },
     error
   );
}
```

**Usage**

The following example demonstrates how to print attachment urls for list items:

```
var listTitle = 'Contacts';
getListItems(listTitle,
  function(items){
     //print items
     for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count(); i++){
        var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);

        //print attachments
        var attachments = item.get_attachmentFiles();
        for(var j = 0; j < attachments.get_count(); j++){
            var attachment = attachments.getItemAtIndex(j);
            console.log(attachment.get_serverRelativeUrl());
        }   
     }
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Comment: it gives me `Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested` error after adding `ctx.load(items,'Include(AttachmentFiles)');` line. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Even you can use SpServices, its gives a easy way to get the attachments from lists on the basis of item ID.